# How to find the max element from an array list of objects?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

`Collections.max(arraylist)` doesn't work, and a regular `for` loop won't work either.

What I have is:

```
ArrayList<Forecast> forecasts = current.getForecasts();
```

`Collections.max(forecast)` gives me this error:

```
The method max(Collection<? extends T>) in the type Collections is
not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<Forecast>)
```

The `ArrayList` holds `Forecast` objects which each has an `int` field for the temperature of each day. I am trying to store the max in an int max.

Comment: Does Forecast class implement Comparable?

Comment: The `forecasts` ArrayList of Forecast, is not an array of int. Both a loop and `max()` work correctly when used appropriately.

Comment: You have to use Compactor interface

Comment: How does not using a regular for loop work? Can you share the code you tried with?

Comment: @PeterLawrey could you please expand on that? If forecasts is not an array of integers, how can I get the max integer value in it?

Comment: @JoshCuevas you get the int value from the Forecast and then get maximum of those values. You don't need to create another collection to do that.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As your `ArrayList` contains `Forecast` objects you'll need to define how the `max` method should find the maximum element within your `ArrayList`.

something along the lines of this should work:

```
ArrayList<Forecast> forecasts = new ArrayList<>();
// Forecast object which has highest temperature
Forecast element = Collections.max(forecasts, Comparator.comparingInt(Forecast::getTemperature));
// retrieve the maximum temperature
int maxTemperature = element.getTemperature();
```

Comment: works flawlessly!

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is use map reduce:

```
Optional<Forecast> element = forecasts
                     .stream()
                     .reduce((a,b) -> a.getTemperature() > b.getTemperature() ? a : b );
```

In this way you could even use use `parallelStream()`

Answer (score 1):

Streams are perfect for these sort of problems.

```
Forecast highest = forecasts.stream()
                            .max((fc1, fc2) -> fc1.getTemp() - fc2.getTemp())
                            .get();
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the simple method that return a max value from arraylist

public static object GetMaxValue(ArrayList arrayList)

{

```
 ArrayList sortArrayList= arrayList;

 sortArrayList.Sort();

 sortArrayList.Reverse();

 return sortArrayList[0];
```

}

Answer (score -2):

I have two ideas. First of all, you used `forecast` in the parameter, but it should be `forecasts`. Also, you never gave your code for the class `Forecast`. I may be wrong, because I didn't see all of your code, but you need to convert Forecast to a `Integer`. Do this by `Integer i = Integer.parseInt(forecasts);` Next use `Collections.max(i)`

Comment: You can only parse a String, parseInt returns an int, not an Integer and once you have just one value there is no point calling max () as it is the maximum.