# How to extract the latest date from an object (which is a list of dates, Java)

Tags: java, sorting, date, collections

I have an object `list_of_dates`, of the following form :

```
[2018-06-18T00:00Z, 2018-06-23T00:00Z, 2018-06-02T00:00Z,...,2018-06-21T00:00Z]
```

I would like to extract the latest date. I can not do this with the help of:

```
//here, I assume object is transformed into list and then sorted.
Collections.sort(Arrays.asList(list_of_dates)); 
return list_of_dates[list_of_dates.length-1];
```

Could you suggest why I get an error?

Comment: *I can not do this*: why? What happens when you do? (That said, you don't need to sort to find the max. Collections has a max() method). Also, please, respect the Java naming conventions.

Comment: what error you get, can share the full code please?

Comment: What type are you using for your dates? `Instant`? `String`?

Comment: When you say you cannot do it as in the question, do you mean it’s a given task that requires you to do it some other way? Would [`Collections.max()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max-java.util.Collection-) be OK, or do you need to use one or more loops?

Comment: Similar questions have been asked and answered more than once before. See for example [How to find the max element from an array list of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43701377/how-to-find-the-max-element-from-an-array-list-of-objects) And use you search engine to find many more.

Comment: 1) Dear all, I am very sorry for a late reply, I was out of the internet. 2) @YCF_L, apparently there was another issue that caused the error. ( I am learning Java from the code of the open source library, called OpenGamma). I still can not understand where exactly the error appears further, as I loose track of the whole program.  3) I do not know what type I am using for dates (the library I study uses threeten project)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code should work fine, here is another solution where you can find the [max](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#max-java.util.Comparator-) or the [min](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#min-java.util.Comparator-)

```
ZonedDateTime[] list_of_dates = new ZonedDateTime[n];
//...
ZonedDateTime maxDate = Stream.of(list_of_dates).max(ZonedDateTime::compareTo).get();
```

Comment: Arrays.asList() returns a list backed by the array. Sorting the list does sort the array.

Comment: this is true @JBNizet this is true, I edit my answer

Comment: Your answer still implies that the OP doesn't sort the array. He does, because sorting the list sorts the array. So his code should work fine.

Comment: Given that the format of the dates are `2018-06-18T00:00Z`, that would appear to be `ZonedDateTime` or `OffsetDateTime` objects, not `java.util.Date`, and not `Instant` (which always shows seconds). --- Also, the type of `list_of_dates` should be an array.

Comment: This is totally true @JBNizet what is the solution then, what the OP want exactly!

Comment: Even shorter would be: `Stream.of(list_of_dates)`.

Comment: I learn many things from this answer, Thank you @DodgyCodeException

Comment: @OleV.V. Yes, `Instant` *seems* more likely, but `Instant.toString()` always outputs seconds *(as I already said in previous comment)*, so it would be `2018-06-18T00:00:00Z`, not `2018-06-18T00:00Z`, whereas `ZonedDateTime.toString()` doesn't output a zero second, so a `ZonedDateTime` with a UTC time zone *will* output `2018-06-18T00:00Z`. `Z` doesn't mean `Instant`, it just means UTC.

Comment: Sorry, @Andreas, I read your comment, but not properly. Deleting mine.